# Keras simple math operation model fails with "Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, backend

I want to define a simple model that uses basic math operations. I tried to implement it using multiple approaches, but the most obvious ones fail, and I would like to understand why.

Let's look at the code:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

x = Input(shape=(3,))
y = Lambda(lambda x: x ** 2)(x)
print y
# Tensor("lambda_1/pow:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
# Works!

y = x ** 2
print y
# Tensor("pow:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
# Fails: TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors.

y = K.pow(x, 2)
print y
# Tensor("Pow:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
# Fails: TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors.
```

As you can see, the output of `y` for all models is almost identical, but the intuitive ones fail for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received an answer: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6443#issuecomment-298259821

> Here both x and y should be the outputs of Keras layers.

x is the output of the Input layer, and in the above case, y was the output of a Lambda layer. Writing custom layers is also possible: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/